# Automatic login concrete 5

Tags: authentication, concrete5

i'm trying to implement an automatic log in in concrete 5: 
suppose that i know username and password, i want to pass them by post to index.php/login/do_login page, but there are problems:

I tryed:
1) to get the cookie and pass it into a curl request:

```
$cc=$_COOKIE['CONCRETE5'];

$strCookie="CONCRETE5=".$cc." ";
$ch = curl_init("http://local.sitename.it/index.php/login/do_login/");
$parametri="uName=correctusernaname&uPassword=correctpass";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parametri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie ); 

$Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In this case the problem was that i couldn't get cookie with $cc=$_COOKIE['CONCRETE5'];

2) to get the cookie by javascript and than to make a ajax post request by JQUERY:

in this case it seems that usename and password can't reach to the login page.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you know the username you don't need the password. You could do this:

```
$ui = UserInfo::getByUserName($username);
$u = $ui->getUserObject();
$userID = $u->getUserID();
User::loginByUserID($userID);
```